# Get-AzureStorageContainer Powershell Command Adding Additional Text

Tags: powershell, azure, storage, blob-storage

I'm trying to run a **powershell command** to **list the blobs in a container**. I found this command and modified it as needed:

*$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName [name].blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net -StorageAccountKey [key]
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx*

The following error is returned - Get-AzureStorageContainer : *The remote name could not be resolved: '**.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net.blob.core.windows.net**'*

I don't understand why powershell is appending the cloudapi.net.blob.core.windows.net. Is there a way to force powershell not to do this? As you can tell im working with Azure Government.

Answer (score 2):

you need to just use `[name]` as an argument to `-StorageAccountName`. it will append to that automatically. so replace `[name].blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net` with `[name]`

Comment: Even when I specify a variable and assigned the full name of my storage account, ex: xxxxx.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net, the additional blob.core.windows.net is appended to the end so it comes out as xxxxx.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net.blob.core.windows.net.  I tried -StorageAccountName $storageaccountvariable.equals('xxxxx.blob.core.usgovcloudapi.net') but that didn't work either.

Comment: you dont need full name, you only need everything before `.blob.core.windows.net` (only NAME, not full url), if you are using gov cloud you need to use endpoint parameter, something like: `-Endpoint "core.usgovcloudapi.net"`

Comment: See [Example](https://i.imgur.com/pnthb1p.png)

Comment: Understood. I took your advice and used -Endpoint, this was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: in this case, consider accepting this answer ;)